# Get URL and set a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Hey, i think this is an easy question.  I have a URL and i want to set one of the directories in a variable.

URL:
`http://www.domainname.com/Irving/For-Sale/Used/Dodge/Ram-1500/2009--Black-Truck/4691335/`

`var usedInventory = _____`

I need a variable that equals "Used"

Let me know if you have any questions!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite follow. You are trying to find the value of the 3rd level directory from the URL?

Comment: Yes, you are correct...sorry if i wasn't very clear! :)

Comment: is it always the 3rd level that you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
js> var url = 'http://www.domainname.com/Irving/For-Sale/Used/Dodge/Ram-1500/2009--Black-Truck/4691335/';
js> url.split('/')[5]
Used
```

In a browser environment, use `location.href` instead of `url`. You don't even have to involve jQuery for that btw.

```
var urlParts = location.href.split('/');
var yourField = urlParts[5];
```

Comment: +1. You can also use `window.location.pathname` to skip the irrelevant host name parts and just split up the path parameters.  In this case, the part required is `[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use PHP to grab the variable from the URL. Since you're using mod_rewrite I'm assuming the variable is named "used". I'm also assuming that you're working in an environment that is PHP.

```
<?php $used = $_GET['used']; ?>

var usedInventory = <?php echo $used; ?>
```

Comment: You should at use `$used = isset($_GET['used']) ? $_GET['used']: '';` to ensure no notice is thrown if the variable is not set.

Comment: Pretty URLs doesn't mean mod_rewrite (and subsequently doesn't mean PHP).  Apache is only one of many web server engines that allows URL rewriting, and other server side technologies can be used with Apache.

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring = "http://www.domainname.com/Irving/For-Sale/Used/Dodge/Ram-1500/2009--Black-Truck/4691335/";
if (mystring.match(/Used/)) {
    alert("Used");
}
```

Comment: He wants to extract it, not check if it contains it - especially not at a random position...